# GitHub Actions Workflow Not Updating GitHub Pages on Dart File Changes in Main Branch

Tags: flutter, dart, github-actions, github-pages

I'm encountering an issue where my GitHub Pages site doesn't update after making .dart file changes in my Flutter project, despite successful workflow execution. The workflow aims to build the Flutter web app and push it to the gh-pages branch. Changes in the main branch reflect correctly, but when pushing generated files (like index.html) to gh-pages, I get a "nothing to commit, working tree clean" message, contradicting my expectations of updating the site.

Here's my workflow configuration:

```
name: Deploy to GitHub Pages

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      my_secret: ${{secrets.SECRET_TOKEN}}

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: subosito/flutter-action@v2
        with:
          channel: 'stable'

      - run: flutter clean
      - run: flutter pub get
      - run: flutter build web --release

      - run: |
          cd build
          mkdir web-deploy
          cd web-deploy
          git config --global user.email user@gmail.com
          git config --global user.name user
          git config --global init.defaultBranch main
          git init
          git remote add origin https://${{secrets.SECRET_TOKEN}}@github.com/user/user.github.io.git
          git fetch origin gh-pages
          git switch gh-pages
          cp -R ../web/* .
          git status
          git add .
          echo "Committing to gh-pages: ${{ github.event.head_commit.message }}"
          git commit -m "${{ github.event.head_commit.message }}"
          git push origin gh-pages
```

The workflow executes without errors if I specify "allow empty commit" flag, and I can see the commit in the gh-pages branch, but the changes are not visible on my GitHub Pages site.

Some things I've considered:

The .dart files are correctly modified in the main branch.
The build and deployment steps complete without errors if I specify "allow empty commit" flag.
I am visiting my app on incognito mode or deleting my cache on the browser but nothing changes.

Questions:

The workflow completes without errors, and the gh-pages branch shows the commit, but the GitHub Pages site doesn't reflect the changes.

Considerations:

.dart changes are confirmed in the main branch.
The build and deploy steps succeed.
Browser cache has been cleared to ensure it's not a caching issue.
Questions:

Is my workflow misconfigured, preventing GitHub Pages from updating?
Could GitHub Pages caching be the issue, and how can I force a refresh?
Have I missed a critical step for content updates on GitHub Pages?
Any insights or suggestions are greatly appreciated!